# WebShphere 8.5 and Hibernate 4.3.1 JTA transaction error

Tags: hibernate, websphere, jta

I am using hibernate 4.3.1 and WAS 8.5. I am getting following error in WAS 8.5. It works fine in WebShpere liberty profile 8.5. Will greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!!

**My hibernate properties configs.**

```
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform
hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.Exception: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException: Could not obtain WebSphere TransactionManager
    at com.bts.clientmgmt.dao.impl.BaseDAO.save(BaseDAO.java:42)
    at com.bts.clientmgmt.dao.impl.NameDaoImpl.saveName(NameDaoImpl.java:44)
    at com.bts.clientmgmt.webservices.CMSWebServiceImpl.addName(CMSWebServiceImpl.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:178)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:222)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:202)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:215)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1071)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException: Could not obtain WebSphere TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(WebSphereJtaPlatform.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext.isLocalTransaction(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext.registerSynchronization(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.TransactionalWorker.performWork(TransactionalWorker.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.processWork(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:247)
    at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.onPostInsert(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at com.bts.clientmgmt.dao.impl.BaseDAO.save(BaseDAO.java:34)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerSet incompatible with javax.transaction.TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(WebSphereJtaPlatform.java:80)
```

Comment: Try to use just org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform=org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform

Answer (score 0):

I get the same "casued by" error like yours. Following solution works for me.
http://nickztechblog.blogspot.com/2011/06/caused-by-orghibernatehibernateexceptio.html

I replace "hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" from "org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereTransactionManagerLookup" to "org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup".